# How Do You Do File Locking in Raku?

Tags: file, locking, raku

I've been trying to figure out how to do file locking in Raku without success. I started looking into fcntl with NativeCall, but then realized that fcntl locks don't prevent file access from other threads. What's the best way to do file locking in Raku?

Comment: Maybe IO lock method is what you are looking for: [lock](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle#method_lock)

Comment: That's embarrassing. I looked all over and didn't see that. Thanks @ValleLukas!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IO::Handle has a [lock](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle#method_lock) and an [unlock](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle#method_unlock) method to lock/unlock files. Locks can be exclusive or shared.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across these Raku-idiomatic phrases and use them a lot, with 'given' topicalizing for brevity/clarity:

Read:

```
    given $path.IO.open {
        .lock: :shared;
        %data = from-json(.slurp);
        .close;
    }
```

Write:

```
    given $path.IO.open(:w) {
        .lock;
        .spurt: to-json(%data);
        .close;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't unlock if the middle line throws an exception, a LEAVE phases may be helpful to ensure that